# Why does initialising from stack yeld weird result in GNU GAS (AT&T)

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I am kind of a noob in assembler. I am trying to initialise variables from the stack (ie. in a practical case their values are pushed to the stack by a third party). The code is similar to this:

```
.data
b:
        .long   0
a:
        .long   0

        .global main
        .text
main:
        push $2
        pop b
        push $1
        pop a
```

Anyway, what I would expect would be to have 1 in a and 2 in b. Instead, I have 1 in a and cruft in b (though it is static between executions). What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: To insert code into your post: Use cut and paste, select the code and then press the `{}` toolbar button to format it correctly.

Comment: I tried, but it went screwy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong 2 things:

1. Not showing the exact code, just something "similar".
2. Not showing how you checked the value.

The code is working as-is:

```
(gdb) p a
$1 = 1
(gdb) p b
$2 = 2
```

Comment: Solved (will accept after the obligatory three minute delay imposed by SO). Thank you very much.

Comment: @ThéoFriberg : As is this question and answer (combination) aren't useful without knowing what your problem was. Can you explain what you did wrong and how that was different from what Jester did? I don't have issue with Jester's answer, It is hard to tell how this question is useful in the current form. I am tempted to close the question as "no longer reproducible"

Comment: I don't think the question to be really useful, the bug was with me failing to format the output right. Mea culpa.

Comment: @ThéoFriberg thanks for the followup. With that in mind, no offense to you, but I'll vote to close the question, as it falls into basically a typographical error or no longer being reproducible. Glad you got it going though.

Comment: Sorry to waste people's time.

Comment: @ThéoFriberg No waste of time! Jester hasn't killed all his braincells yet ;)

Comment: @MichaelPetch everybody keen on killing my brain cells today!